# AuthorizationServer.ReadAuthorizationRequest return null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm using asp.net MVC 4.0 and building **OAuth** host using **DotNetOpenAuth** library.
I'm trying to implement **Authorise** method in **OAuthController** :

```
[Authorize, AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Authorise()
{
    using (OAuth2AuthorizationServer server = (new OAuth2AuthorizationServer(new X509Certificate2(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AbsolutePathToPfx"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePassword"]), new X509Certificate2(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AbsolutePathToCertificate"]))))
    {
        AuthorizationServer authorizationServer = new AuthorizationServer(server);

        EndUserAuthorizationRequest pendingRequest = authorizationServer.ReadAuthorizationRequest();
        if (pendingRequest == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException((int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Missing authorization request.");
        }
        //**
    }
}
```

and I'm getting `pendingRequest == null`!

I know for sure that method `IClientDescription GetClient(string clientIdentifier)` in `OAuth2AuthorizationServer` should be called in `ReadAuthorizationRequest` - but in fact it doesn't call in my case.

Does anybody has any guesses why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out issue. To cut long story short - client wasn't inplemented correctly. Client is responsible for containing such info as :

- client_id
- redirect_uri
- state
- scope
- response_type

and not all fields were set up

Answer (score 0):

If you are working off of code sample as described here: https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Security-scenarios

Here are some sample values to call the OAuthController  Auth() action:

```
- client_id=RP
- response_type=code
- redirect_uri=https://localhost/RP/Secure4ownAuthSvr/OAuth
- scope=http://localhost/demo
- state=""
```

Your call would look like this (using Fiddler):

```
GET
http://localhost/OAuth2/Auth?client_id=RP&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost/RP/Secure4ownAuthSvr/OAuth&state=&scope=http://localhost/demo

POST
http://localhost/OAuth2/Auth
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
client_id=RP&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost/RP/Secure4ownAuthSvr/OAuth&state=&scope=http://localhost/demo
```